# not geting push notification from firebase console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have implemented all the steps regarding implementing the push notification ,but when i tested notification the console its not coming to the iPhone, but when i tested with production apns certificate n with password n token from the "https://pushtry.com/" its working fine. i am not able to rectify why this is heppening.i have also enabled the push-notification from capability section.thanks
     Here below my app delegate code

```
mport Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder,UIApplicationDelegate,MessagingDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{

    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyB5HWsalLBmBFjLC3NjTUF2KB7i5zvz45k")
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyB5HWsalLBmBFjLC3NjTUF2KB7i5zvz45k")


      let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        // It is For Notification Allow Authentications
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (isGranted, err) in
            guard isGranted else { return }
            self.getNotificationSettings()
            if err != nil {
                //Something bad happend
                 print("Erroo ocured......")
            } else {
                print(" Success.........All good")
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                Messaging.messaging().delegate = self   // it is very important to Generate Firebase registration token, otherwise "didReceiveRegistrationToken" method will not called.

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }

         FirebaseApp.configure()
      return true
    }

    func getNotificationSettings() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications() })
        }
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)
    {
        print("Firebase registration token::::::: \(fcmToken)")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(fcmToken, forKey: "deviceToken")

    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }



    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        NSLog("[RemoteNotification] didRefreshRegistrationToken: \(fcmToken)")
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        // Print the error to console (you should alert the user that registration failed)
        print("APNs registration failed: \(error)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        //NSLog("[RemoteNotification] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) didReceiveRemoteNotification for iOS9: \(userInfo)")
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
            //TODO: Handle foreground notification
        } else {
            //TODO: Handle background notification
        }
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }



    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        // show the notification alert (banner), and with sound
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }



    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // tell the app that we have finished processing the user’s action / response
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        if(application.applicationState == .active){
        print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in foreground")
        }
        if(application.applicationState == .inactive)
        {
        print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in background")
        }
        completionHandler()
    }





  func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }
  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }



    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        self.saveContext()
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps that need to be done to test the push notification:

- Make sure you test it with a real device
- You can fetch remote instance id in the function didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken as follow, then send push notification directly to the device token using your Firebase console:

> ```
> func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
>     InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
>         if let error = error {
>             print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
>         } else if let result = result {
>             print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

- If it doesn't work, check whether you have uploaded correct APNs Authentication Key or APNs Certificates in your Firebase console settings.

Answer (score 0):

**First You should check all certificates kinds of stuff are correct **
After that In appdelegate

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // START register for notifications
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()        
        // END register for notifications
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
        } else if let result = result {
            print("Result \(result)")
        }
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.hexString

}
```

**Also Upload your p.12 file into firebase console**

Comment: i have done all the step n also i have uploaded .p12 file to the firebase console, still not able to get notification